# Unpermitted Params using Polymorphic Association in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-7

[image]

Based on image above, I do a simple example.

**Model: Person**

```rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :personable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**Model: Customer**

```rb
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :person, as: :personable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person
end
```

**Controller: customers_controller**

```rb
def new
  @customer = Customer.new
  @customer.build_person
end

def create
  @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
  @customer.save
  redirect_to customers_path
end

private

def customer_params
  params.require(:customer).permit(:id, person_attributes: [:id, :name, :personable_type, :personable_id])
end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_with(model: customer) do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for customer.person do |form_fields| %>
    <%= form_fields.label :name %>
    <%= form_fields.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
  <div>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I run using Rails Console it's okay, according code below.

```
c = Customer.create()
Person.create(name: "Saulo", personable: c)
```

But when I run using view and controller, i receive the error below.

```
Unpermitted parameter: :person. Context: { controller: CustomersController, action: create, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00007fdad45e3650>, params: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "customer"=>{"person"=>{"name"=>"Alisson"}}, "commit"=>"Create Customer", "controller"=>"customers", "action"=>"create"} }
```

I believe that the error its in method customer_params, but i don't found a way to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails is expecting the `person` attributes to be nested under `person_attributes`, but the form is sending them under `person` instead.

To fix this, ensure that `fields_for` is correctly setting up the fields to be nested under `person_attributes` in the form:

```
<%= form_with(model: [customer, customer.build_person]) do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :person_attributes, customer.person do |person_form| %>
    <%= person_form.label :name %>
    <%= person_form.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This should generate the correct parameter name (`person_attributes`) for the nested attributes.

Comment: Thank you so much James. I've been looking for the solution for a week. However, I just informed **:person_attributes** and it worked.

Comment: Happy to help :) If the answer solved your problem, it'd be great if you could mark it as accepted.